# Azure AD B2C - How to see user's extensions

Tags: azure, attributes, azure-ad-b2c

I followed the tutorial [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/service-consent) to be able to ask user's consent and store it in the AD as custom extension (from what I did understood...)

The custom flow seems to work well (consents are asked during signup process) but then I want to verify them in the AD (and maybe delete them from the admin console for new tests) I did not found where I can see them...

I tried to retrieve them through MS Graph API explorer (I started in on my tenant on the URL https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?tenant=xxxx.onmicrosoft.com) and I try to call the endpoint https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/ae29dab2-...-f4d813ca6dec/extensions but I get no extensions back...

Am I doing things right ? Is there another way to verify what are the current user's custom extensions ?

I think those extensions are well stored, because when I try to login again with the same user, no consents is asked anymore...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/UsersObjectId`. It will return their extension attributes in the response.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works well and I am able to see the custom attribute I was looking for !
Do you know why it is only on `beta` version and not the `v1` ? Do you know how I can remove "manually" (via the admin console or the Graph API) those custom attribute ?

Comment: Ok, for the "manual" update, I did found myself. Just use a PATCH operation on the same endpoint with data that you want to change in the body

Comment: But anyway Jas Suri, do you know why it is only on beta version and not the v1 ?

Comment: We aren't expecting this endpoint to change in regards to extension attributes, it just has not been moved into v1 yet, likely due to the rest of the object properties.